# show a single object if an array have multiple object with same value

Tags: json, ionic2

i am making a url call so that it returns a json. when i try to display it to my html i am getting repetition of values which must be avoided.

```
export class ProductListPage {
 GetProductsTags: any = [];

searchProduct() {
    var url = 'myUrl';       
    this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        var getdata=JSON.parse(data.Response); 
        console.log(getdata);  
       this.storage.set("productTags", getdata);   
    });
}

fileter() {
        this.storage.get("productTags").then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
             this.GetProductsTags = data;
        })
```

JSON response from url

```
 [
        {
            id: 1,
            color: "red",
            size: 'S',

        },
        {
            id: 2,
            color: "blue",
            sizes: 'M'
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            color: "red",
            sizes: 'L'
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            color: "blue",
            sizes: 'XL'
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            color: "blue",
            sizes: 'XXL'
        }

    ];
```

And in my html

```
 <button (click)="fileter()">filter</button>
 <button (click)="searchProduct()">filter</button>
 <ion-label>item</ion-label>
     <ion-item *ngFor=" let item of GetProductsTags; let i=index ">
        <ion-label>{{item.color}}</ion-label>
         <ion-checkbox color="dark"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
```

So in my view i am getting the color of each and every product as a list, like i am having 5 product so 5 color in list "red , blue, red, blue, blue, blue".

What i need is only "red, blue" in that list i need some logic or idea to fix this.
Could someone help me

Comment: Use a pipe which removes elements having duplicate colors from the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use method like following to remove duplicates.

```
public removeDuplicates(){
   for(int i=0;i<this.GetProductsTags.length;i++){
      if(!(this.colors.indexOf(this.GetProductsTags[i].color) > -1)){
         this.colors.push(this.GetProductsTags[i].color);
      }
   }
}
```

initialize the colors array as global. Then you can use that array to iterate that.

Comment: were or when do i have to invoke this function

Comment: You can call this function as follows, 
`fileter() {
        this.storage.get("productTags").then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
             this.GetProductsTags = data;
             this.removeDuplicates();
        })`

Comment: does this GetProductsTags refers to the empty array, i used the above code getting error

Comment: check it now.. I missed the `this` scope.. I corrected it :)

Comment: i changed int to var and copyed above still i get this err."  TypeError: this.GetProductsTags[i].get is not a function
TypeError: this.GetProductsTags[i].get is not a function
    at ProductListPage.removeDuplicates   "

Comment: try with replacing `this.GetProductsTags[i].get("color")` with `this.GetProductsTags[i]["color"]`

Comment: That means GetProductsTags has no items. pleas check if it has items or not by adding `console.log(this.GetProductsTags)` before the  for loop in my method

Comment: used like this it worked "  this.colors.push(this.GetProductsTags[i].color); ". Update the code so others could use it

Answer (score 0):

```
var uniqueColor = [];//declaring empty array
for(var data in getdata){
    if(uniqueColor.indexOf(getdata[data]['color'])==-1)//check the array, if the current color in this iteration is already pushed into the unique queue
      uniqueColor.push(getdata[data]['color']);// push the color to the unique if not already present
}
console.log(uniqueColor);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.